# Comparative in subordinate clauses

Tags: subordinate, clauses, сравнительная-степень, сравнительный

Someone told me that it is incorrect to say `"Я не люблю людей, моложе меня"`. The correct syntax, she said, is `"Я не люблю людей, кто моложе меня"`.

I got to know that, when using a comparative referring to people on a subordinate clause, the subordinate clause may not be introduced by the comparative (*моложе*), but by a relative pronoun (*кто, который*, etc.).

But, what about things other than people?

If I want to tell *"I don't like cars older than 5 years"*, which of the following alternatives is valid?

**1.** Я не люблю машин, что старше пяти лет.

**2.** Я не люблю машин, которые старше пяти лет.

**3.** Я не люблю машин, которым более пяти лет.

**4.** Я не люблю машин, чему более пяти лет.

Comment: `Я не люблю людей моложе меня` is fully identical to the English `I don't like people younger than me`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange advice. `Я не люблю людей, кто моложе меня` is ungrammatical. Sounds like the kind of mistake an English speaker would make. **Кто** never introduces a subordinate clause without a preceding form of **тот** (in the appropriate gender, case, and number), unless the main clause's verb is imperative.

**Я не люблю людей моложе меня** (no comma) is correct and that's how you should say it.

**Я не люблю тех, кто моложе меня** is correct too but a bit too bookish for everyday speech.

1. **Я не люблю машин, что старше пяти лет.** — Accidentally sounds like a line of poetry. You'd rarely find **что** outside the poetic register (unless, of course, it's a **тот, что** two-parter).
2. **Я не люблю машин, которые старше пяти лет.** — Okay.
3. **Я не люблю машин, которым более пяти лет.** — Better.
4. **Я не люблю машин, чему более пяти лет.** — If anything, this can be understood to somewhat clumsily try to say that the speaker has disliked cars for over five years.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Now it's clear... кто always after тот, тех, etc. If a comparative can introduce a subordinate clause, then it's ok to tell **Я не люблю машин, старше пяти лет**?

Comment: @swrutra Yes. But, again, you don't need the comma.

Comment: "Я не люблю людей(,) что моложе меня" (not sure about comma) - sounds ok, although old fashioned. Notice how "что" is used instead of "кто" in some cases, like in "Что он за человек?".

Comment: @swrutra **Я не люблю машинЫ старше пяти лет/которым более пяти лет** in my opinion is the correct case (Accusative) ending in this particular sentence, `машин` is Genitive which with *love* applies to animate objects, `я не люблю машин` has the connotation of a sensual/romantic love and not of preference or fondness... one can say `я не вижу машин`, but not `я не люблю машин`